# How to print this json string to list?

Tags: php, json

I constructed a below json getting value from database tables.
 Now I want to  to print below json to un-ordered list in php.
 How can i print this below json to list.

Here is my array and expected output.

```
{
    "id": "6",
    "name": "aaaaa",
    "actove_from": "2000",
    "firstlevelrelations": {
        "1": {
            "name": "bbbbb",
            "active_from": "1990"

        },
        "5": {
            "name": "cccccc",
            "active_from": "2003"

        },
        "4": {
            "name": "dddddd",
            "active_from": "1992",

            "2": {
                "name": "fffff",
                "active_from": "1990"

                            }

        },
        "7": {
            "name": "ggggg",
            "active_from": "2015"

        },
        "9": {
            "name": "hhhhhh",
            "active_from": "1990",

            "10": {

                "name": "yyyyy",
                "active_from": "1997"

            }
        }

    }
}
```

ouptut:

```
<ul>
    <li>aaaaaa</li>
     <li>2000</li>
     <ul>
         <li>bbbbbb</li>
         <li>1990</li>
         <li>ccccc</li>
         <li>2003</li>
         <li>dddddd</li>
         <li>1992
            <ul>
                <li>fffff</li>
               <li>1990</li>             
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>gggggg</li>
         <li>2015</li>
         <li>hhhhhh</li>
         <li>1990
            <ul>
                <li>yyyyyy</li>
               <li>1997</li>             
            </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) takes a JSON encoded string and converts it to a PHP associative array. Now loop on the array and output your HTML.

Comment: When looping the array, i want to print two list (li) in a single loop execution instead of printing one by one.

Answer (score 2):

```
// decode the string as assoc array
$json = json_decode($your_json_string_here, true);

function menu( $arr ) {
    $result = "";
    foreach( $arr as $key => $item ) {
        // if the item is array calls the menu function
        $result .= "<li>" . (is_array($item) ? menu($item) : $item)."</li>";
    }
    return "<ul>" . $result . "</ul>";
}

echo menu($json);
```

This will create the desired output (but without the indentation)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve all of it for you but this should get you where you want to go.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        //start building your sublist
    }else{
        //start building your list
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$jsonvar = json_decode('{"id":"6","name":"aaaaa","actove_from":"2000","firstlevelrelations":{"1":{"name":"bbbbb","active_from":"1990"},"5":{"name":"cccccc","active_from":"2003"},"4":{"name":"dddddd","active_from":"1992","2":{"name":"fffff","active_from":"1990"}},"7":{"name":"ggggg","active_from":"2015"},"9":{"name":"hhhhhh","active_from":"1990","10":{"name":"yyyyy","active_from":"1997"}}}}', true); // now you can access like an array.

$id = $jsonvar['id'];
// so on and so forth

//to access the firstlevelrelation
for($i=0;$i<$jsonvar['firstlevelrelation'];$i++){
    echo $jsonvar['firstlevelrelation'][$i]; // here you will be accessing each element inside the firstLevelRelation field.
    // so for example, you wanna acess the name from each element.
    $nameInsideFirstLevelRelation = $jsonvar['firstlevelrelation'][$i]['name'];

}
```

Or if you indexes can change the name

```
foreach($jsonvar as $key=>$value){
    //if it is just a simple value
    $valuesInsideYourJson = $value;

    //if it is an array of other objects.
    if(is_array($valuesInsideYourJson)){
        foreach($valuesInsideYourJson as $val){
            // this in inside the firstlevelrelation
            // do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Here you have the access to the raw data, now you print them between DOM element tags.

Comment: Seems dangerous to rely on fixed array index names like that unless you know for certain that it will never change.

Comment: in his problem, it seems to always have the same index.